# delete results fetched from another page using jquery ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a jquery ajax php add, delete, display application using swicth case so to compact the code . I am able to insert and display the records but delete action can not be performed. here's the code i am using

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>FIRST NAME</th>
<th>LAST NAME</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="showtable">
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><button name="submit" id="submit" onclick="crudaction('add','');">ADD NEW</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script>

show();
function show(){


var sub = "display";
$.post("crudaction.php",{action : sub}, function(data){
$("#showtable").html(data);
});

}

function crudaction(action,id){
var querystring;
alert(action);
switch(action){

case "add": 
querystring ='action='+action+'&fname='+$("#fname").val()+'&lname='+$("#lname").val();
break;

case "delete":
querystring = 'action='+action+'&id='+id;
break;
}
$.ajax({
url : "crudaction.php",
type : "POST",
datatype : "JSON",
cache : false,
data : querystring,
complete : function(){


alert('success');
show();
}

});

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**crudaction.php**

```
<?php

include_once("dbc.php");
$ob1 = new controller();
$action = $_POST['action'];
if(isset($action))
{

switch($action)
{

case "add":
mysqli_query($ob1->con,"insert into ajaxtable(fname,lname) values('".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['lname']."') ");      
break;      
case "delete":

mysqli_query($ob1->con,"delete from ajaxtable where id='".$_POST['id']."'");
break;
case "display":

$res = $ob1->display();  
foreach($res as $k=>$val){
echo "<tr>
<td>".$val['fname']."</td>
<td>".$val['lname']."</td>
<td><a href='#' onclick='crudaction('delete','".$val['id']."'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>";

}  
break;  

}
exit();

}

?>
```

**dbc.php**

```
<?php

class controller{

private $server = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $dbname = "search";
var $con;


function __construct(){

$this->con = $this->connect();

}


public function connect(){

$this->con = mysqli_connect("$this->server","$this->user","$this->pass","$this->dbname") or die("coudn't connect".mysqli_error($con));
return $this->con;
}


public function display(){

$res = mysqli_query($this->con,"select * from ajaxtable");
if($res->num_rows>0){
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
$result[] =$row;            
}
if(!empty($result))
return $result; 


}

}
}

?>
```

cant figure out where the problem is ??

Comment: Firstly check `querystring` before sending request, after that add an echo to check  `case "delete":`.

Comment: it doesn't get the action value "delete" when i click on the crudaction function of delete link .. but script is working fine for adding ..

Comment: in index.php, where you called "alert(action)": does it alert "DELETE"?

Comment: no it doesn't alert . because data is coming from another page "crudaction.php" and script written on index.php is not working for delete link ... while it alerts for add which is wriiten on index.php...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's a quote escaping problem and a missing closing-parenthesis in your crudaction.php code:

```
<td><a href='#' onclick='crudaction('delete','".$val['id']."'>Delete</a></td>
```

it should be

```
<td><a href='#' onclick='crudaction(\'delete\',\'".$val['id']."\');'>Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: no both showing same code on page source .. if  I simply add a css from jquery on response data it doesn' work too .... is it so beacause data is coming from another page..??

Comment: @phpdevp please double-check the code snippet I quoted in this answer; html data returned from ajax is not properly formatted (the "onclick" function breaks your html structure).

Comment: i've copied your code but still no change... i've tried this "$(".one").css("background","red");" on index.php providing class on "<a href='#' class="one"onclick='crudaction(\'delete\',\'".$val['id']."\');'>Delete</a>"  even this doesn't show any red background on delete links...

Comment: please check the presence of javascript errors in your browser's console; is there something like "$ is not defined"?